# How do a System of Record and a Database relate

Tags: database

[Wikipedia defines System of Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_record) as:

> a data management term for an information storage system (commonly
> implemented on a computer system running a database management system)
> that is the authoritative data source for a given data element or
> piece of information.

I might not be really understanding it, but in simple terms, isn't this just a database?  If I am speaking amongst a group of developers, why not just say "database"?  If I am misunderstanding, what is the relationship between a System of Record and a database?

Why might a System of Record have a particular name?  This question is akin to "Why name a particular browser Firefox?"  If it is just a database, I would just call it "the database".

Comment: You should link to your sources.

Comment: [That page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_record) is about a legal or policy context, not a technical programming context.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about legal or policy terminology, not about a programming problem.

Comment: No.  A system of record is a concept, not a database. You are conflating a logical entity with a physical one.  My Excel spreadsheet can be a system of record if I want it.